# Qt Creator Deploy to Remote Linux Target

Tags: qt, deployment, build, qt-creator, embedded-linux

I used Buildroot to build Qt for a target BeagleBoard. I pointed Qt Creator at the qmake file generated by Buildroot and added Buildroot's toolchain to the Build & Run configuration option under the Qt Creator 'Tools' menu, added a 'Generice Linux Device' under Qt Creator's 'Tools' menu, and used the test configuration tool in that menu to test connection to the Device. That test passed and said everything was fine. Dropbear ( SSH ) is installed on the BeagleBoard and I can SSH to it from my terminal just fine. When I setup the Build and Run configuration options for the Example AnalogClock project in Qt Creator it successfully builds the demo ( make exits with no errors ) but hangs with the compilation output message of 'Connecting to Generic Linux Device...'. I've waited 1/2 an hour and it never gets past this step. Below are some screenshots of my setup. I've done this before not using Buildroot but just building Qt from source and was able to successfully deploy. I assumed that since my 'Generic Linux Device' setup passed the Qt Creator 'Test' tool and since I can SSH to the machine that everything should work. Does anybody have any ideas on what could be wrong? Is it at all possible that the qmake built from Buildroot would somehow have been configured to where I cannot deploy to the remote Linux Device if my toolchain works and I can successfully build the demo app? Please help - thanks in advance.

EDIT - Updates:
The difference between what I am trying to do now and before on a different target when remote deployment did work is that now I am using wireless to connect to the device. Previously I was connected to the target board through a router but everything was hardwired. Should that matter? I would think the 'Test' device configuration would fail then.. Here is the output where it hangs from Qt Creator:
14:54:32: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited normally.
14:54:32: Connecting to device...

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok the solution was that I needed an SFTP server on the BeagleBoard. The 'test' tool in Qt Creator only checks SSH connection not that you can SFTP. The solution was to install the vsftpd package within buildroot and then it worked.

Comment: Hi. I have a problem like you. could you help me? what you mean install vsftpd package? how to install it? and install on board or on pc?

Comment: Install it on the target board. If you use something like Buildroot, then you just need to include that package so it gets built and deployed to your target board.

Answer (score 1):

thank you for your post but when I change this line in tiny6410 it work(I did not install vstft on target board):

```
In /usr/local/etc/sshd_config
Line:
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/sftp-server
must be:
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/local/libexec/sftp-server
```

refrence: http://www.friendlyarm.net/forum/topic/6036#28428